# Nifi/Minifi: How to read multipart/form-data request

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using `HandleHttpRequest` processor to receive a request with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. The request contains a text param and a file (`Content-Type: image/jpeg`). How can I read this parameters, and put them into attributes?

Comment: are you using the version that splits multipart to multiple flowfiles?
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpRequest/

Comment: No I'm not... the request appears as a single flowfile

Comment: what version of nifi are you using?

Comment: I'm using Nifi 1.7.0. By the time I started this project, it was the only version compatible with the latest version of Minifi

Comment: with this version i see the only option - to pass file to server and try to expand multipart there with script